# Which vessel could a pumping vessel in the left middle side of forehead be?

Tags: blood-pressure, forehead, blood-vessels

There is a vessel located on the left middle side of my forehead which keeps pumping for few times noticeably every few minutes, my question is:

What are vessels flowing on the left-mid side of the forehead that can be felt pulsating?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

<sup>Map of the superficial arteries (the arteries close beneath the skin), taken from [ClinicalGate](https://clinicalgate.com/head-and-neck-overview-and-surface-anatomy/), which I believe they have taken from [Gray's Anatomy for Students](https://books.google.de/books/about/Gray_s_Anatomy_for_Students.html?id=SJBqAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Map of the deeper arteries, *ibid*</sup>

I'm unsure which you consider the left-mid side of your forehead, but you probably felt one of the larger arteries like the [superficial temporal artery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superficial_temporal_artery) or the [facial artery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_artery), but please check for yourself.